# C++ pointer to a pointer to an array consisting of n elements

Tags: c++, pointers

C++ how to initialize this pointer:

```
int (**aLines)[2] ?
```

I'm trying to initialize:

```
int (**aLines)[2] = (int(**)[2]) new int*[10];
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    aLines[i] = new int[5][2];
}
```

Comment: What is your requirement? Initialization of **ptr using 2D Array?

Comment: whether do you want to store two pointers of 2D array ?

Comment: If you need to cast the result of `new`, you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 2):

In C++, a vector should be your default choice of container. Naked `new`'s should be avoided as well. Avoid dynamically allocating objects unless necessary. Following these guidelines will result in code that is safer and easier to maintain.

Here's how to make a vector of ints, a pointer to said vector, and a pointer to said pointer.

```
std::vector<int> v = {3,8,1,6};
std::vector<int>* p = &v;
std::vector<int>** pp = &p;

std::cout << p->front() << std::endl;

std::cout << (*pp)->back() << std::endl;
```

I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to do in the code that you have shown, but there's certainly a better way. If you describe what you're trying to achieve we can help you more.

Comment: You could also make `std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int> > >` if I understand well the OP code.
To init, it would be in the likes of `myVect(10, std::vector<std::vector<int> >(5, std::vector<int>(2)))`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I needed without STL.

Answer (score 0):

I have included a code example of how to allocate, use and deallocate a static array with a dynamic 2D array.

I hope it is useful.

```
void allocate_print_and_deallocate_numbers() {
    // Allocate
    int **aLines[2];
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        aLines[i] = new int* [10];
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            aLines[i][j] = new int [5];
            for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
                aLines[i][j][k] = i + j + k; // Assign a number
            }
        }
    }

    // Use
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
                std::cout << aLines[i][j][k] << std::endl;
            }
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    // Deallocate
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            delete [] aLines[i][j];
        }
        delete [] aLines[i];
        aLines[i] = NULL;
    }
}
```

Comment: He is actually trying to get A[m][n][2]; your code gives A[2][m][n]

Comment: Alright. His question was very unclear to me, so I had to improvise.